# Read csv file, sum particular column, return values

Tags: python, list, csv

So I have this CSV file with values as follows:

```
Destination Address  Count   Device Action
10.0.0.1             5       accept
10.0.0.2             4       deny
10.0.0.3             6       accept
10.0.0.2             8       accept
10.0.0.3             6       deny
10.0.0.1             2       accept
```

and so on.(there are also other columns in the csv file which i have omitted)

I have written the following code to sum up the counts of each unique address for which the action is accept and return the [IP, sum] values:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Traffic to blacklisted IP.csv') as oublip:
    oublip_list = list(csv.DictReader(oublip))    
action=[column['Device Action'] for column in oublip_list]
daddr1 = set(b['Destination Address'] for b in oublip_list)
daddrl1 = [column['Destination Address'] for column in oublip_list]
sumcount1 = [int(column['Sum']) for column in oublip_list]
daddr1o = []
for act in action:
    if act=='accept':
        for daddr in daddr1:
            sum=0
            for index, c in enumerate(daddrl1):
                if c==daddr:
                    sum=sum+sumcount1[index]
            daddr1o.append([daddr, sum])
daddr2o = [list(t) for t in set(map(tuple, daddr1o))]
daddr2o.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
print(daddr2o)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: Have you looked at `Counter`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Your data isn't a 'CSV' file. Your code references columns that don't exist in your data. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are all working too hard. `pandas` handles this perfectly:

```
import pandas
df = read_csv('YOUR_PATH_HERE', sep='WHATEVER_SEP_U_USE')
print(df['COLUMN_NAME_HERE'].unique().shape[0])
# or
print(df['COLUMN_NAME_HERE'].value_counts())
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,1,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,1,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['AA1233445','AA1233445', 'rmacy','Idaho Rx','Ab123455','TV192837','RX','Ohio Drugs','RX12345','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
print(df)
# use code below to get the number of unique values
print(df['A'].unique().shape[0])
#output is 5


# use this code below for the count for each unique value 
print(df['A'].value_counts())
#output below 

5.0    3
1.0    3
3.0    2
4.0    1
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**:
To sum the counts based on a certain column:

```
df2= df[df['Action']=='Accept']
df3 = df2.groupby('Destination Address').sum()
print(df3['Count'])
```

You may have to change the column names a bit

Comment: which gives you an error? the code I posted or the code you are trying to run on? From searching that error is due to passing a string object instead of using actual lists or dictionaries, where are you getting that error?

Comment: That was my mistake, I got it to work but this code simple counts the number of times the values is repeated but I need to sum the values in the column "Count".

Comment: if you are using `pandas` like my example above. To get the sum of a dataframe column `print(df['Count'].sum())`

Comment: I also need it to return the "Address" value along with the sum of the values for those addresses for which the action is "accept"

Comment: in my example above i use `print(df['A'].value_counts())` For you it depends on your column. So `print(df['Adresses'].value_counts())`. This will return the number of times each address appears. Is this what you are asking for? I may be missing something

Comment: In the sample I have provided since action=accept for both values of 10.0.0.1, it should return the sum as 7.

Comment: Almost....Is there anyway we can only get it to sum the values when the value in column "Action" is "accept"

Comment: Also it prints the Name of the column and dtype at the end, how can I get rid of that?

Comment: Okay... I updated the answer. For future reference- please post all of this information in your question as the comment chain is getting long :) It will be difficult for future viewers to follow this progression. But for your case i'd seriously recommend getting familiar with `pandas`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and advice, really appreciate it :)

Comment: My pleasure! if a post has answered your question, be sure to mark as "Answered" by click the "Check Mark" icon

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you again, but your code just returns the following: "Series([], Name: Sum(Aggregated Event Count), dtype: int64)"

Comment: It's going to be very hard to debug this in comments and without me seeing the data. My first guess would be to make sure that the column names are correct and the values are correct. These are both case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

from collections import defaultdict
Dont both with cvsreader if you dont have to you should just need to split. Use a hash to map a ip address to a unique count, use a defualtdict to auto intialize the count to 0 on a new ip address.

```
counts = defaultdict(int)
with open(r'C:\Input\traffic to IP.csv', "r") as csvfile:
  for line in csvfile.readlines() :
    l = line.split()
    if l[2] == 'accept' :
      counts[l[0]] += int(l[1])

print "\n".join([ "%s : %d"%(k,v) 
        for k,v in counts.iteritems()])
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I convert this piece of code into a function so that I can reuse it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're after:

```py
import csv

def get_device_counts(event_list):
    device_counts = {}
    for event in event_list:
        if event['Device Action'] != 'accept':
            continue
        if event['Destination Address'] not in device_counts:
            device_counts[event['Destination Address']] = 0
        device_counts[event['Destination Address']] += int(event['Sum'])
    return device_counts

def print_device_counts(device_counts):
    for key in sorted(device_counts, key=device_counts.get, reverse=True):
        value = device_counts[key]
        print('%s: %d' % ( key, value ))

event_list = csv.DictReader(open('data.csv', 'r'))
device_counts = get_device_counts(event_list)
print_device_counts(device_counts)
```

Using the following data:

```
Destination Address,Sum,Device Action
10.0.0.1,5,accept
10.0.0.2,4,deny
10.0.0.3,6,accept
10.0.0.2,8,accept
10.0.0.3,6,deny
10.0.0.1,2,accept
```

Gives the following output:

```
10.0.0.2: 8
10.0.0.1: 7
10.0.0.3: 6
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!!! When I wrote a function to implement my code, it returned erroneous results. Is there anyway I can convert this code into a function?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!